# Requested Version Error AWS Simple Notification Service .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, amazon-web-services

I am encountering an error in my application that is using version 2.3.55 of the AWS SDK for .NET. The problem occurs when attempting to publish a message to a Simple Notification Service Topic that I have created. The error is caught by a try catch statement. The error I am receiving when I attempt to publish a message is:

```
The requested version ( 2010-03-31 ) is not valid.
```

It appears that the SNS Client gets this version from the SNS Config object used in it's construction. I am unable to change this attribute (SimpleNotificationServiceConfig.ServiceVersion) of the SNS Config because it is a read only attribute. I checked both packages.config and App.config for a field that would set the default for this attribute however I wasn't able to find anything. I also wasn't able to find this error anywhere on the AWS API. Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

I have found the source of error. I was attempting to use a service url for a Queue instead of an SNS. All I had to do was update this url to the correct one and I was able to publish. This error message was technically correct, as that version is not valid for SQS. If anyone stumbles across this in the future, check your URL!